# Dynamically changing styles in Angular 6 using Environment Variable

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, angular6

I am trying to change styles dynamically in Angular 6 using environment variables.

And I am able to do that,

here is how my file structure looks like:

```
src
 -app
 -assets
 -environments
 -scss
  -theme1.scss
  -theme2.scss
  -_variables.scss
  -styles.scss
```

Inside my _variables.scss, I am importing theme1.scss and theme2.scss

And in the styles.scss, I am including _variables.scss

Inside theme1.scss and theme2.scss, I am having all the styles and variables wrapped in a class.

Eg:

```
.theme1{
 $input-btn-focus-width:0;
$input-btn-focus-color:transparent;
$input-btn-focus-box-shadow:none;
$primary-color: #0378C5!default; 
$primary-grad-start: #0269ad;

.logo {
   width: 150px;
 }

}
```

Similarly, theme2.scss will go in the similar fashion.

And in the component.ts file, I am changing the class name as follows:

```
this.selectedTheme = environment.customer==""? "theme1": "theme2";
```

Now, the problem is that I have to wrap every component with the dynamic class.

Eg:

```
<app-login [class]="selectedTheme"></app-login>
```

And there are so many components and I don't want to do it for every component.

Is there any way I can add this selectedTheme dynamically to the root element i.e. body of the Angular application so that I can avoid adding the class to each and every component.

Comment: In Angular 6, in angular.json you can use the "replacement" tag to replace two files (but it's not "dinamically else in building phase). You can use the method showed by Shekhar in  https://shekhargulati.com/2018/01/16/dynamically-loading-css-in-angular-5-application/

Comment: The way he does is by adding a css file but I cannot do that with an scss file as it is not being processed.

Comment: there are multiple ways to do that but just let me see if I understood this. You have several CSS each of them with a set of styles that would defined a theme. And in some way in your code you want to have the possibility to switch between themes, BUT you need to do that applying the "theme class" in only one place and that would be applied to all components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I wrapped my app.component.html in a div.

Comment: Please accept an answer, if that is the one you were looking for ;)

Comment: Can't accept my own answer within two days of posting it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [host-context](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-context) feature of angular. Apply `selectedTheme` to your root component, e.g `app.component`. And then use it in any child component:

```
\:host-context(.theme1) .logo
  width: 150px
```